# How to save form data of component A when going to component B and retrieve data when coming back to component A

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, auto, angular4-forms, autosave

I have a situation where I want to save my uncompleted reactive-form data of **component-A** while going to **component-B** and want to **retrieve the data back** to show in the same form when coming back to **component-A**.

Please guide me , if there is a solution in **angular-4**.

**Thanks**.

Comment: You'll want to start here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 2):

You could **store it in a variable in a service file** and prefill the form using the value in the variable when you come back to component A from B.

Comment: Yes I thought about the same solution of using a service, but I wanted to know if there are some smoother way using angular's by default feature if any for example using the router module or any other. , Thanks for your time.